# Touchscreen/Digitizer support

Tags: system, hardware, touchscreen, wacom

I am rather new to linux. Does elementary OS provide support for touchscreens and (wacom) digitizers? I am using a thinkpad tablet 10 and am working a lot with the pen.

Thank you for your help,
Scarabaea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elementary OS does support wacom tablets. There is even a hardware icon in "System Settings" under "Hardware" that says "Wacom Tablet". I don't use a wacom tablet, but it is still there so I imagine it must support wacom tablet, otherwise there is no reason the "Wacom Tablet" icon should be there.

The real problem that can occur is what happens when you plug in your wacom tablet. If there is one, you can come back and troubleshoot and post the problem then.